# Moving a Git repository from a Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, git, projects, solution

I am only a very beginner user of git and have a C# Visual Studio solution (sln) with 5 projects in it. I already understand that I need to have also 5 different git 'projects' for that.

Currently these Git projects are stored in a directory in my sln directory but I rather have it on a separate disk, including history information etc.
How should I do this (in a safe way)?

Edit/update:
Is this the same as using the clone command from inside the git extension in visual studio:
I get the output:

c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe clone -v --bare --progress "G:/Data/Eigen/Informatica/KorgKronosTools/KorgKronosTools/" "d:/git/KorgKronosTools"
Cloning into bare repository d:/git/KorgKronosTools...
done.
Done

Comment: It's possible to have a VS solution with many projects exist in the same git repository.  Are you thinking of sub-modules?

Comment: @JaredPar I currently have to commit each of my VS projects (5 in 1 solution) into git One by One ... Is there are way to commit a complete VS solution instead of individual projects?

Comment: Sure. Just create a new git repository at the root and do `git add .`.

Comment: @JaredPar However I couldn't find a git menu when selecting a solution, I only see them when I select one of the 5 VS projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a remote repository:

```
cd c:\backup\
mkdir project-X 
cd project-X
git --bare init
```

then go to your existing repository and inside it:

```
git remote add origin file://c:/backup/project-X
git push origin master
```

now every time you think its a good time to backup, run `git push origin master` and the changes you made in the existing directory will be pushed to the "remote" directory.

Comment: in addition, you may might want to get the git plugin for VS 2010 as well as get your gitignore file setup.

Comment: @AdamD I'm already using the git plugin but never heard of gitignore file setup (is it an option or a plugin?), I'm currently not at my PC where git is installed.

Comment: its just a file ``.gitignore`` with some rules which files are to be ignored, you should stick everything VS generates automatically in it.

Comment: I will try later this evening when I'm behind my development PC.

Comment: Yup, PizzaPill is right, the git plugin does it for you but if you had the solution and tried to add it to a git repo that already exists, i had issues with the gitignore not being created so it was just a heads up.

Comment: @AdamD I really don't know anything about the VS git plugin, I was just explaining what the ``.gitignore`` does ;) Your heads up will be appreciated in the future!

Comment: @PizzaPill glad to help! i guess the wording confused me. i dont recall the sequence of events but my gitignore was missing and git checked in dlls, obj and bin folders, sou files, the works. took me a while to figure out how to fix that.